# My unsaved changes directive needs to work for all forms with different names

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a directive that opens a modal to alert user of unsaved changes and I need it to check for form dirty with different unknown names. I have tried to use scope to access the forms name and *this* but have not been successfull. I can access the form name with elem[0].name but it does not carry the form $dirty value.

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" name="myFormName" confirm-on-exit>
Cool form html
</form>

app.directive('confirmOnExit', ['modalService', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$state', function (modalService, $rootScope, $stateParms, $state) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',       
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, formCtrl) {

        onRouteChangeOff = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', routeChange);

        function routeChange(event, newState, newParams, fromState, fromParams) {

            if (scope.myFormName.$dirty) {
                return;
            }

            event.preventDefault();
            var modalOptions = {
                closeButtonText: 'No, I\'ll stay and save them.',
                actionButtonText: 'Yes, Leave and Ignore Changes',
                headerText: 'Unsaved Changes',
                bodyText: 'You have unsaved changes. Do you want to leave the page?'
            };

            modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then(function (result) {

                if (result) {
                    onRouteChangeOff(); //Stop listening for location changes
                    $state.go(newState); //Go to page they're interested in
                } else {

                    $state.go(fromState); //Stay on the page and have tab revert to fromState
                }
            });

            return;
        }
    }
};

}]);
```

Comment: I have also used attrs.name to access the form name but no dice on attrs.name.$dirty.

Comment: Try `scope.$eval(attrs.name)` to get the scope variable.

Comment: Thank you @quantumwannabe for your quick answer.  Any idea how to test for dirty form using scope.$eval?  if (scope.$eval(attrs.name).$dirty) shows $dirty as undefined.

Comment: Odd, in my simple test (in my answer below) `$dirty` was defined. Could you make a fiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Thanks again @quantumwannabe but I am up against a deadline and did not have the time to fiddle. I used Michael's route change service and voila.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a service for observing route changes where you register all forms you want to *spy* on. The registration of a form will then be handled by your directive.

I put together some code below:

```
app.directive('confirmOnExit', function (FormChanges) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',       
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, formCtrl) {
            FormChanges.register(scope, attrs.name);
        }
    };
}]);

app.factory('FormChanges', function (modalService, $rootScope, $state) {
    var formNames = [];
    var dirtyCallbacks = {};

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, newState, newParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        var hasDirtyForm = false;

        // Check all registered forms if any of them is dirty
        for (var i = 0; i < formNames.length; i++) {
            var name = formNames[i];
            if (dirtyCallbacks[name] && dirtyCallbacks[name]()) {
                // got a dirty form!
                hasDirtyForm = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!hasDirtyForm) {
            // Nothing is dirty, we can continue normally
            return;
        }

        // Something was dirty, show modal
        event.preventDefault();
        var modalOptions = {
            closeButtonText: 'No, I\'ll stay and save them.',
            actionButtonText: 'Yes, Leave and Ignore Changes',
            headerText: 'Unsaved Changes',
            bodyText: 'You have unsaved changes. Do you want to leave the page?'
        };

        modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then(function (result) {
            if (result) {
                // clear the current forms
                formNames = [];
                dirtyCallbacks = {};
                $state.go(newState, newParams); //Go to page they're interested in
            } else {
                $state.go(fromState, fromParams); //Stay on the page and have tab revert to fromState
            }
        });

        return;
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
        // be sure to clear the registered forms when change was successful
        formNames = [];
        dirtyCallbacks = {};
    });

    var service = {
        // Register a form by giving the scope it's contained in and its name
        register: function (scope, name) {
            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                // e.g. an ng-if may destroy the scope, so make sure to remove this form again
                service.remove(name);
            });
            formNames.push(name);
            dirtyCallbacks[name] = function () {
                return scope[name].$dirty;
            };
        },

        remove: function (name) {
            delete dirtyCallbacks[name];
        }
    };

    return service;
});
```

I wasn't able to test it, so it may contain some small errors - just let me know and I will check. Also note that my code is **not** minification save!

Comment: Your code did indeed work. And I made my deadline. Thanks, this is quite an educational tool for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `scope.$eval(attrs.name)` to get the variable associated with the name in the name attribute. It should behave just like the normal scope variable and you should be able to access all of its properties.

This snippet shows that checking for `$dirty` works:

```js
angular.module('test', [])
.directive('testdirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',       
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, formCtrl) {
            console.log(scope.$eval(attrs.name), scope.$eval(attrs.name).$dirty);
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
Open Console
<div ng-app="test">
  <form testdirective name="testform"></form>
</div>
```